# Prevent multiple users from viewing the same page

Tags: asp.net

What's the optimal way to prevent multiple users from viewing the same page? I want to detect if another user is currently viewing, and if there is, display a message "Someone else is viewing this, please try again in a few minutes"

Comment: Do you want to prevent users from editing the same record?

Comment: @BlackFrog, in a way, but more complicated. It's a multi-row editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set it to application state, which is checked, and if false, set to true on `Page_Load` event. I'm guessing that checking whether someone has stopped viewing the page is more complicated, since you can't know if the user closes the browser, or leaves the specific page some other way.

Comment: Thank you. This is a good solution. I can set another variable to hold the time of locking. If the page is attempted viewed within 5 minutes of that time, the lock is enforced. If not, the lock is reset and the first user is prevented from doing further actions on that page.